# Como recarregar uma activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Estou com o seguinte problema, em minha aplicação tenho uma `ListView` na `act 1`, e faço um cadastro na `act 2`, porém quando eu finalizo o cadastro eu também finalizo a `act 2`, com isso retorno para `act 1`, o problema é que o meu método de pesquisar já carregou a minha `ListView` da primeira vez que eu executei a `act 1`. Como faço para chamar esse método novamente?

Comment: Chame o metodo notifyDataSetChanged() de seu Adapter sempre que há alterações nos dados. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70&t=17m38s

Comment: muito obrigado esse problema eu consegui resolver, porem surgiu outro se puder me ajudar eu agradeço !                        http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/154431/manter-os-dados-em-uma-variavel-da-primeira-act-apos-voltar-da-segunda-act-pelo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você tem que explorar o [ciclo de vida](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html?hl=pt-br) da sua `Activity` utilizando o `onResume()`. Teria que colocar sua busca novamente dentro do método.

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    // coloque sua busca novamente aqui

}
```

#### Ciclo de vida

Conforme o usuário navega, sai e retorna para o seu aplicativo, as instâncias `Activity` no aplicativo transitam entre diferentes estados no ciclo de vida. Por exemplo, quando a atividade começa pela primeira vez, ela fica em primeiro plano no sistema e tem o foco do usuário.

Durante o processo, o sistema Android chama uma série de métodos do ciclo de vida na atividade, onde você define a interface do usuário e outros componentes. Se o usuário executa uma ação que inicia outra atividade ou alterna para outro aplicativo, o sistema chama outro conjunto de métodos do ciclo de vida em sua atividade conforme ela fica em segundo plano (onde a atividade já não está visível, mas a instância e seu estado permanecem intactos).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

#### Detalhes

- [Como gerenciar o ciclo de vida da atividade](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html?hl=pt-br)
- [Pausando e reiniciando uma atividade](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html)

Answer (score 0):

Faça seu cadastro na act2 e encerre a act2. Faça sua busca no onResume da act1 (o método deve ser chamado na activity mesmo, e ele é automaticamente chamado quando a tela se inicia ou quando uma outra tela sai de cima dela) e chame `meuAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` (não se esqueça de preencher o adaptar com os novos dados) que o adaptador sozinho vai se atualizar. (tudo no onresume).

```
@Override
public void onResume(){ // escreva esse método na act1
    super.onResume();
    // Código da busca
    meuAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

O interessante é que, quando voce faz isso no onResume, toda vez que a act1 abre, o onResume vai ser executado sozinho. Então não precisa reescrever o código de busca no onCreate.

Comment: muito obrigado esse problema eu consegui resolver, porem surgiu outro se puder me ajudar eu agradeço !                        http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/154431/manter-os-dados-em-uma-variavel-da-primeira-act-apos-voltar-da-segunda-act-pelo