# manter os dados em uma variavel da primeira act apos voltar da segunda act pelo up button

Tags: android-studio, listview, android-activity

Estou com o seguinte problema , tenho uma list view na act1 q depende de uma variável para ser carregada, quando eu finalizo minha act2 ou volto pelo botão de voltar do android (botão inferior) o valor da variável é mantido, porem quando eu volto usando o botão de voltar da aplicação o valor da variável é zerado

observação: minha list view esta sendo carregada pelo método onResume.

Comment: 1 - pode explicar melhor o que seria "botão de voltar da aplicação"? É um Button comum que mata a act2 ao ser clicado?
2 - pode explicar melhor "list view na act1 q depende de uma variável para ser carregada"?

Comment: quando vc coloca um parentActivityName no manifest, ele gera um botão para voltar a activity anterior na parte superior esquerda da aplicação, a informação que vai filtrar a pesquisa quando eu fizer o select esta salva em uma variável String, no meu select tem um where usando o valor dessa variável, pela primeira vez ela faz tudo certo, porem quando eu volto usando esse botão superior esquerdo eu perco o valor dessa variável String, perdendo assim a informação necessária para completar meu select

Comment: consegui eu criei uma variável static e ela não esta mais perdendo os valores !   ex: static String valor;